# Convergence of independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

### The Problem

We have sequence of independent random variables $(X_n)_{n\ge1}$ ~ $U[\frac1n,1]$.
I want to prove that $$\frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{n}$$
converges almost surely and find the limit.

### Theorem's I used

**1.** If $(X_n)_{n\ge1}$ is sequence of independent random variables , $S_n=X_1+X_2+...+X_n$,

and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{Var(X_n)}{n^2} <+\infty$, then $\frac{S_n-E(S_n)}{n} \rightarrow 0$ almost surely.

**2.** $X$ ~ $U[a,b] \Rightarrow Var(X)=\frac{(b-a)^2}{12}$

**3.**  $X$ ~ $U[a,b] \Rightarrow E(X)=\frac{a+b}{2}$

### My Justification

We know that $Var(X_n)=\frac{(1-\frac1n)^2}{12}=\frac{(n-1)^2}{12n^2}$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{Var(X_n)}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)^2}{12n^4}<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{12n^4}<+\infty$.

$E(S_n)=E(X_1+X_2+...+X_n)=E(X_1)+E(X_2)+...+E(X_n)=1+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{4}{6}+...+\frac{n+1}{2n}$.

So by my theorem I see, that :

$$\frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{n} \rightarrow \frac{1+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{4}{6}+\frac{5}{8}+...+\frac{n+1}{2n}}{n}$$ almost surely.

> Is that correct ? I am little bit confused because of having on the
>   right side number's dependent on $n$.

Comment: By the theorem you cited, we know that $$\frac{S_n-\mathbf{E}[S_n]}{n} \to 0$$ almost surely. Also, by direct computation, we have$$\frac{\mathbf{E}[S_n]}{n}\to\frac{1}{2}$$as $n\to\infty$. (You may either utilize the formula you derived, or alternatively, just apply the Stolz-Cesaro theorem to show that $\lim \frac{\mathbf{E}[S_n]}{n}=\lim\mathbf{E}[X_n]=\frac{1}{2}$.) So by adding two computations, we obtain$$\frac{S_n}{n}\to\frac{1}{2}\qquad\text{a.s.}$$

Comment: I understand ! Thank you very much for answer !